# Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Table 'XXXX.XXX_session' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a problem with copying the databases, i am using `XAMPP and 1.8.3-3 and Mac OS`, i copied the databases from `xamppfiles->var->mysql` and uninstalled the XAMPP, then i install the XAMPP again because the MySql Databases wasn't work, after install the XAMPP all the services work well, so i copied the old databases again to x`amppfiles->var->mysql` and i tried to browse the websites, but i get this error::

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Table 'XXXXX.xxxxx_session' doesn't exist SQL=DELETE FROM `xxxxx_session` WHERE `time` < '1398851285'
```

I opened the Phpmyadmin and tried to open the database, some tables are open and some of them give me like this error::

```
 #1146 - Table 'XXXXX.xxxxx_session' doesn't exist
```

Where is the problem!

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: Please confirm if you have XXXXX database in the server?

Comment: I am working on localhost, and the database is exists, and all the tables are exists in the database, but some of them are open and some of them are not open!

Comment: Could be the database credentials you have entered in the configuration.php file aren't correct. Just a guess

Comment: Thanks Sathish for your replay, But the problem is in all the databases i copied, i have many sites and all the databases of them have the same problem!

Comment: I noticed somthing, the tables that didn't open, doesn't have The (Indexes) But the others have Indexes!

Comment: I don't why it's happen! i just copied the databases to safe folder, and return it to orginal place when i install XAMPP again! i didn't change anything!

Comment: Could be worth reading this: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=791765

Answer (score 0):

You just open file 'configuration.php' and focus to parameter "$dbprefix", make sure that if you have correct data prefix like database.